# display:none; and display:block; in a naviation menu

Tags: navigation, html-lists, css

I'm trying to understand a bit more of some CSS coding. I've borrowed a navigation bar. The HTML code is like this:

```
      <ul>
        <li>
        <a href="">Business</a>
            <ul> 
            <li><a href="#">sub menu item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">sub menu item 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

The CSS:

```
   ul li 
   {
   display: block;
   position: relative;
   float: left;
   font-size:12px;
   top:15px;
   }

   li ul { display: none; }

   #navigation ul
   {margin:0px; padding:0px;}


   ul li a 
   {
   display:block;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: white;
   padding: 20px 30px 20px 15px;
   }

   ul li a:hover 
   { 
   background: #F89623;
   }

   /*submenu position*/
   li:hover ul 
   {
   display:block;
   position:absolute;
   left: -30px;
   top:51px;
   }

   li:hover a 
   { 
   background: #F89623;
   }

   /*Background when you mouseover subitems*/
   li:hover li a:hover 
   { 
   background: #FFDEB0;
   }

   /*top nav only*/
  #navigation > ul > li > a {
  font-size: 16px;
  border-top-left-radius:10px;
  border-top-right-radius:10px;
  }
```

I don't understand some of the display tags. What does `li ul { display: none; }` do?

Also `display: block;` what does this do in my code (above)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS display:none means hide element; display:block means show element.

Take a look at descendant selectors - http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors

In your case,

```
 li ul { display: none; }
```

means that those ULs that are descendants of LIs will not be shown (display:none vs. display:block);

In other words,

```
<ul id='parentUL'>
   <li id='childLI'>
      <ul id='childUL'>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

childUL will not be shown based on this CSS.

Comment: Clarification: `display:block;` does not mean "show element". It means "display as block element". In this particular case, your statement is true, but if the element is naturally `inline`, `table` or something else, it might mess things up if you simply use `display:block;` to toggle visibility.

Answer (score 2):

**li ul { display: none; }** will Hide the ul list which is defined under li tag.

**li:hover ul { display:block; .. }** this will show hidden ul list block defined under li tag

Answer (score 1):

```
li ul { display: none; }
```

Hides ul tags inside an li tag.

```
display: block;
```

This will display like a div or paragraph. (It will make it visible)

Comment: Not a paragraph, they are inline elements.

Comment: display: block elements are not inline. For inline you use display: inline.

Comment: Yes exactly. A div is a block level element. A paragraph is an inline element. By setting display block it will not display like a normal paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

It simply toggles between the display modes — how the element should behave on the page. As you might have guessed, `none` means it will not display at all. The two other most common display types are `inline` and `block`.

Inline elements are elements such as `<a>`, `<span>` or `<img>`. It will position itself on the same line as the previous content.

Block elements are elements such as `<div>` or `<h1>`. It will position itself on a new line, and generally fill the entire width of the container. Block elements can also be manipulated with a padding, border, margin etc. (the box model).

There are lots of other display modes, such as `table` or `inline-block`. I'd advice you to read up on display modes. Here's a good ressource to get you started: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html

EDIT:
I know `<img>` is technically not a pure `inline` element. It does display in-line, but unlike the traditional `inline` elements, it may have some `block` attributes, such as width or height. In reality it might be more line a `inline-block` element, but that's a discussion for another day. ;)